# "Error in Parcel Selection" in SaeX in ArcGIS 9.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, vba, saex

I am using SaeX extension in ArcGIS 9.3 and whenever i try to select a parcel it gives:

> Error occured in parcel selection.

Other tools are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation of VBA manually will solve the problem. The VBA can be manually installed from the Installed Directory which Usually is C Drive > Program Files (for 32 bit windows) and Program Files (X86) (For 64 bit installation) > ArcGIS > Support > VBA i.e. either

> C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Support/VBA/1033/

or

> C:/Program Files (X86)/ArcGIS/Support/VBA1033/

There is a file `VBAOF11I`. Install it.

Answer (score 3):

Installing arcgis did not install visual basic properly. Manually installing VBA solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

install VBA Setup file from ArcGIS9.3 Desktop Backup to resolve the problem of parcel selection. if you have installed higer GIS version rather than 9.3, it should not required VBA. although if you have installed Windows 7 ultimate sp 1 required VBA but do not require in windows professional.